# Diffusion equation with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been looking for the solution of the following diffusion equation and I haven't been able to find it.

Can anyone help me, please?

$$U_t=kU_{xx} \\
U(x,0)=f(x)\\
U(0,t)=0 ;U(L,t)=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

Considering the answer underneath, to get the Jacobian could I do the following:

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial U_s}{\partial x} \frac{\partial U_s}{\partial t} \\
\frac{-\partial U_s}{\partial t} \frac{\partial U_s}{\partial x} 
\end{bmatrix}

I got this from:

[Complex function and Jacobian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828689/complex-function-and-jacobian-matrix)

And once I do this, I proceed getting the determinant to find a $z$ from the equation:$$(U_s)_t=(U_s)_{xx}$$

Big thanks,

Emeric

Comment: I do not understand why you are saying that the problem has periodic boundary conditions. Moreover, isn't the initial condition involving $f$ enought to specify the solution at later times?

Comment: As I understand, $f(x)$ is just my initial distribution that it will change at later times and then, the sinus in one of the bourders, is it not a periodic boundary condition?

Comment: I would say no, "periodic boundary condition" means that $U(x,t)$ is periodic over the spatial domain $[0,L]$, namely $U(0,t)=U(L,t)$. The initial condition must be consistent with this requirement: $U(0,t=0)=U(L,t=0)=f(0)=f(L)$. In other words, "periodic boundary condition" means that you have to solve the differential equation over a spatial domain that has the topology of a "circle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $z\in{\mathbb C}$ such that
\begin{equation}
U_S(x, t) = \Im \left(\frac{e^{z x} - e^{-z x}}{e^{z L} - e^{-z L}}A e^{i(\omega t + \phi)}\right)
\end{equation}
satisfies the equation and the boudary conditions (but not the initial conditions). Then write the problem satisfied by
\begin{equation}
V(x, t) = U(x, t) - U_S(x, t)
\end{equation}
In order to get the value of $z$, let us compute
\begin{equation}
(U_S(x, t))_t = \Im \left(\frac{e^{z x} - e^{-z x}}{e^{z L} - e^{-z L}}A i\omega e^{i(\omega t + \phi)}\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
k(U_S(x, t))_{xx} = k \Im \left(z^2\frac{e^{z x} - e^{-z x}}{e^{z L} - e^{-z L}}A e^{i(\omega t + \phi)}\right)
\end{equation}
Hence if one chooses $i \omega = k z^2$, the equation $(U_S)_t = k(U_S)_{xx}$ is satisfied. Assuming $\omega$ and $k$ are positive, it follows that
\begin{equation}
z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2 k}}(1 + i)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mean that I need to get the Jacobian of that function and find z (complex number)? And the solution for $u(x,t) is with zero for the initial conditions? Thanks a lot

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could help me a bit more with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Compute $(U_S)_t$ and $(U_S)_{xx}$ and choose $z$ so that the two are equal.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to know if I get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your idea with the jacobian. See my edits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought that the J symbol was the jacobian. What is it then? Thank you again

Comment: This is how mathjax and latex render the imaginary part (`\Im` directive)